# How to trigger focusout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-focusout

I have a focusout event

```
$('.alpha').on("focusout", function () {...});
```

and I want want to trigger it from somewhere else in the code.

I tried `$('#input12').focus().blur();` 
and also tried `$('#input12').trigger("focusout")`

edit: I am using a dynamically generated elements.

but no luck there...

the element `#input12` has the class name `alpha` so I expect The focusout event to be triggered.

Is there any way of getting it done?

here is a jsfiddle example of when I am trying to do https://jsfiddle.net/jnmnk68d/

Comment: Have you tried `$('#input12').trigger('blur')`?

Comment: is this a dynamically generated element?

Comment: Can you share full code please to reproduce your issue

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `$('#input12').trigger("focusout")` works fine for me. I suspect that you are adding the elements dynamically after the script has initialised. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I am using dynamically added elements. I edited my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You need to delegate your events to a non-dynamic parent element.**

In this example, we listen for `focusout` events on the `form` but only fire our function if the event's target matches the selector (in this case `".alpha"`). This way the event can be fired on any elements that match now or in the future.

```
$("form").on("focusout", ".alpha", function() {
    console.log("focusout happened!");
});
```

Here's a full demo which allows you to see how using delegated events we are able to trigger the event on dynamically inserted content.

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").on("focusout", ".alpha", function(e) {
    console.warn("focusout triggered on " + e.target.outerHTML);
  });

  //example trigger
  //click the link to trigger the event
  $("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#input12").trigger("focusout");
  });

  //demo injecting content
  //click the create button then focus out on the new element to see the delegated event still being fired.
  var i = 12;
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = "input" + (++i);
    $(this).find("fieldset").append("<input id='" + id + "' class='alpha' placeholder='" + id + "' />");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="input12" class="alpha" placeholder="input12" />
    <input type="submit" value="create new" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<a href="#">trigger on input12</a>
```

Comment: @itay312 You should update your question to include the actual code you are using. It might be that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, took your advise and it worked after calling the trigger event inside a setTimeout function

Answer (score 3):

Using `[0]` on the jQuery element works! Also kontrollanten options works too! And doing a normal trigger on `focusout` too!

```js
$(".alpha").on("focusout", function(e){
  console.log(e.type, true);
});

//option 1
$('#input12')[0].focus(); //vanilla
$('#input12')[0].blur(); //vanilla

//option 2
$('#input12').trigger('focusout');

//option 3
$('#input12').trigger('blur');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="alpha" id="input12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example taken from the [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) docs.

```js
var focus = 0,
  blur = 0;
$("p")
  .focusout(function() {
    focus++;
    $("#focus-count").text("focusout fired: " + focus + "x");
  })
```

```css
.inputs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.inputs p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>focusout demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="inputs">
    <p>
      <input type="text"><br>
      <input type="text">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="focus-count">focusout fire</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Maybe if you add your full code I can be of better help?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

See this code, it will call focusout 1second after focus has happend.

```js
$('.alpha').on("focusout", function() {
  console.log('FOCUSOUT!');
});

$('.alpha').on("focus", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    self.focusout();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="alpha" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what seemed to be wrong with my code..
first of all I changed my event to use delegation and  I connected it to a non dynamic element (element that was not added dynamically) just as some here advised.
I also needed to call the trigger function inside a setTimeout because it turns out that it takes a while to render the dynamically added element, so using the setTimeout did the trick.

Thank you all for helping out!